# Recreate Kubernetes deployment with 0 downtime on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, kubernetes-deployment

I have a deployment on Kubernetes (AWS EKS), with several environment variables defined in the deployment .yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myApp
  name: myAppName
spec:
  replicas: 2
  (...)
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MY_ENV_VAR
          value: "my_value"
image: myDockerImage:prodV1
(...)
```

If I want to upgrade the pods to another version of the docker image, say prodV2, I can perform a rolling update which replaces the pods from prodV1 to prodV2 with zero downtime.

However, if I add another env variable, say MY_ENV_VAR_2 : "my_value_2" and perform the same rolling update, I don't see the new env var in the container. The only solution I found in order to have both env vars was to manually execute

```
kubectl delete deployment myAppName
kubectl create deployment -f myDeploymentFile.yaml
```

As you can see, this is not zero downtime, as deleting the deployment will terminate my pods and introduce a downtime until the new deployment is created and the new pods start.

Is there a way to better do this? Thank you!

Comment: I have not tried this myself but I would have thought that if you re-`apply` the same yaml file with the changes (i.e. the additional variable) you'd get a rolling update (no downtime) where the new pods will contain the new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example you might want to test yourself:

Noice I used `spec.strategy.type: RollingUpdate`.

**deployment.yaml**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        env:
        - name: MY_ENV_VAR
          value: "my_value"
```

Apply:

```
➜  ~ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
➜  ~ kubectl exec -it nginx-<hash> env | grep MY_ENV_VAR
MY_ENV_VAR=my_value
```

Notice the env is as set in yaml
Now we edit the env in deployment.yaml:

**deployment.yaml**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        env:
        - name: MY_ENV_VAR
          value: "my_new_value"
```

apply and wait for it to update:

```
➜  ~ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
➜  ~ kubectl get po --watch
# after it updated use Ctrl+C to stop the watch and run:
➜  ~ kubectl exec -it nginx-<new_hash> env | grep MY_ENV_VAR
MY_ENV_VAR=my_new_value
```

As you should see, the env changed. That is pretty much it.